# How to use F# to unit test C# logic

Tags: unit-testing, f#

I am learning F# on my own and am trying to sneak some F# into the workplace.
As a result, I would like to write unit tests in F# to test C# logic.

Can anyone provide me a simple example of an F# unit test targeting a C# method and verifying a C# property as a result of exercising that method?

**UPDATE:**
Here's an example. When a value is provided for first and last name, how do we unit test (in F#) that GetFullName returns first and last name?

```
namespace MVVMExample
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _firstName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }

        private string _lastName;

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works exactly as you would do it in C# - what test-framework are you using? And what is the class/method you want to unit-test (give us at least the signature) - as it is we could only guess

Comment: btw: there are no C#/F# properties/methods - in the end (after compilation) it's all the same ;)

Comment: I am using FsUnit and NUnit. I left this question abstract for a reason. I am brand new to the language and would like different examples from the community.

Comment: what about this http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work-3/ - look if you add an example of an C# function you want to test we could turn this into a good and valuable question but as it is it's really to generic/broad

Comment: Hi Carsten, I have a provided an example of a C# class that I would want to test in F#.

Comment: so you want to test the `PropertyChanged` right ... sadly this is just as sad as with C# - I'll try to write something

Comment: Yes Carsten. I would like to test that the property was updated. NOTE: Sorry for acting out on my frustration. But I just don't know F# at all. As a result, I get frustrated when people ask me to try to write an answer within a language that I do not comprehend. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a very simple test for this `ViewModel` using *NUnit* could look like this:

### testing `GetFullName`

here is a possible test for this function:

```
[<Test>]
member __.``GetFullName = "Jon Doe" if FirstName = "Jon" and LastName = "Doh"``() =
    let vm = ViewModel()
    vm.FirstName <- "Jon"
    vm.LastName <- "Doe"

    Assert.AreEqual("Jon Doe", vm.GetFullName())
```

### testing `PropertyChanged`

```
[<TestFixture>]
type ``ViewModel Unit Tests``() = 

    [<Test>]
    member __.``a PropertyChanged event should be raised if the FirstName was changed``() =
        let vm = ViewModel()
        let mutable lastChangedProperty = ""
        vm.PropertyChanged.Add (fun e -> lastChangedProperty <- e.PropertyName)

        vm.FirstName <- "Tom"

        Assert.AreEqual("FirstName", lastChangedProperty)
```

Of course this is not really *functional* but I think it should be reasonable clear for the given problem.

as you can see it's basically the same you would expect from a C# test - the only *F# feature* I used are the function/class names in ``` ``...`` ``` which makes the output in your test-runner look nicer:

[image: ReSharper Testrunner output]

### Code Walkthrough

- the `[TestFixture] class Test {...}` just translates into `[<TestFixture>] type Test() = ...`
- a `[Test]` method is just `[<Test>] member this.MyTestFunction() = ...` (`this` only if you need it - as you can see I did not so I used the idiomatic *I-don't-care* `__` placeholder - see in F# you can name your `this`-*reference* any way you want - and you have to do it on each class-member.
- as I want to change the `lastChangedProperty` string if the event is fired I declared it `mutable` (so you can use the assign operator `<-`)
- to add an event-handler you can just use the `.Add`function on the event
- `(fun e -> ..)` is an lambda - in C# this would be `e => ...`

### disclaimer

of course if you want to use this viewmodel in say a WPF application you should make sure to dispatch to the UI-Thread, etc. which would make the test more nasty but for your example a simple **red-green** cycle should work ;)

I hope this helps you out (but of course it does not really show the advantages of F# as the test here is ugly side-effecty)

Comment: yes I am aware that I misspelled `John Doe` ... but I ain't gonna change it ....

Comment: Again, I want to incorporate F# at work. I'll start off with some unit tests written in it and then gradually implement utilities and ultimately business models.

Comment: https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Me653fbd136db8b28dd9acfd730be6415o1&pid=15.1 :D